# Datasource and delegate for tableView in a tableViewCell Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I need to make an inner tableView and tableViewCell deque with identifier Cell2 just like it's outer tableView & tableViewCell which deque with identifier Cell. The outer is completed with its datasource and delegate, however when I'm trying to connect inner tableView and tableViewCell I don't know where to connect its delegate/datasource to.. do I make a new class that subclass from what? Please help out in SWIFT language or SWIFT2 no OBJECTIVE C Please! Thank you guys!

Comment: Please provide some code. What are the "inner" and "outer" tableviews?

Comment: There's really not a need for code. it's just a way of saying the hierachy of it. Imagine this, in storyboard. You have a ViewController -> outerTableView -> outerTableViewCell -> innerTableView -> innerTableViewCell. In order for a TableView to use a dynamic tableViewCell.. it deque it with a unique identifier, in this case the outerTableViewCell contains the inner stuff. however, how do you get the inner stuff to deque also?

Comment: That really does not make any sense reading it. It does require code, so we can truly see what you trying to do and offer a real solution. Are you using a container that holds the inner tableView?

Comment: In addition. You basically for the outerTableView you connect to datasource and delegate which those protocols are implemented in the ViewController. However, once it get into the innerTableView, you want to implement another seperate set of datsource/delegate, but how do you create a seperate model or class to handle this? If it's not handle you will just basically get a default tableView. This question has been kind of answer in objective C on stackoverflow somewhere, but not in swift.. and I'm having a tough time. Any idea will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show me some code. I know how tableViews work, but I don't know what you mean by inner and outer tableviews.

Comment: It's not a coding problem, being that it's spread across multiple classes. I mean inner and outer just by naming covention. It's hard to show because it's all in storyboard.

Comment: I can code, it's not a coding issue. Let me define the structure so it's better understand. To replicate my project. I have a View Controller, then I have a tableView then I have tableViewCell in that... and in that tableViewCell it contains another tableView which contains another dynamic tableViewCell.

Comment: Class ViewController: UIViewController,  UITableViewDatasource, UITableViewDelegate ----> contains protocols inplementation to deque all that stuff.. now I have a subclass call "subCell" which is subclass of UItableViewCell which contains all the objects and labels etc...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

Firstly, you will need to make IBoutlet from innerTableView to your subClass for mine is subCell which inherits from UITAbleViewCell. Than in awakeNIB -> You would put self.innerTableView.delegate = self, self.innerTableView.datasource = self, implement requirement for protocols of uitableview datasource and delegate

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand this you have put your inner table view in main tableview's cell, so you can confirm your inner tableviews data source and delegate in your outer UITableviewcell class. First drag your tableview outlet in UITableviewcell class which you made for your cell and then confirm it in awakefromnib() you can write inside awakefromnib() method like

```
youroutletnameofinnertableview.datasource = self 
youroutletnameofinnertableview.delegate = self
```